# How should a Westerner visualise Chinese civilisation under the various dynasties?

Tags: china, medieval-china, ming-dynasty

I have a decent knowledge of European history (if I say so myself!) but, like many Englishmen, my grasp of Chinese history is very poor, and, over the past few months, I've taken some modest steps towards putting that right.

It's been said many times that **Han Dynasty China is roughly equivalent to the Roman Empire**, and, indeed, the parallels between those two contemporaneous superstates are fascinating. Extending that idea a bit, I've drawn up the following aide-memoire to Chinese history:

- The **Han Dynasty** corresponds to the **Roman Empire**;
- The **Tang Dynasty** corresponds to the **Byzantine Empire**;
- The **Song Dynasty** corresponds to the **Plantagenets**;
- The **Ming Dynasty** corresponds to the **Tudors and Stuarts**;
- The **Qing Dynasty** corresponds to the **Hanoverians**.

The above is very useful for giving me an intuitive feel for **when** each dynasty was in power, but it doesn't help me to visualise how each dynasty **looked**. Comparing, for example, the Roman Empire to the Tudors: the Roman elite wore togas, and their soldiers wore the famous *lorica segmentata* and carried short swords and large shields; whereas the Tudor elite wore ruffs (sometimes of hilarious proportions) and their soldiers carried rapiers, halberds and primitive firearms. **But how would I visualise the difference between, say, a Han and a Ming nobleman?** I know it's just a mark of my own ignorance, but Chinese history for me, visually, is just an undifferentiated mass of silks, fireworks and long fingernails. How *should* I visualise it?

Comment: "should" is a difficult term; it is implicitly a solicitation for opinion.  I see the question already has downvotes & closevotes.  Separate from that is the problem that a Marxist is going to have a radically different answer to this question than a Whig might, and a feminist historian might argue that there was no difference between any of them (no disrespect intended; part of the point is that we're painting with a very broad brush here, and we're obscuring details which are very important to each discipline). This is an interesting question; how can we make it better?

Comment: Is there a commonly agreed upon source for visual history of Chinese history? I know for Western fashion/costume design there are some fairly standard references, it seems plausible that there would be for Chinese history.

Comment: Would the question be damaged if the title were "How to visualize Chinese history?"

Comment: I agree. Very interesting question, but needs to be rephrased.

Comment: @MarkCWallace I'd consider that too broad.

Comment: For what it's worth, I (the OP) am 100% on board with rephrasing the question to allow it to fit better with this site. I'm just waiting for those more experienced than myself to tell me what to write.

Comment: @TomHosker Thanks - I'm not convinced I've got it right yet, but let's give it a couple of hours to see if wiser minds can contribute - at any case, let's not close the question while we're revising.

Comment: @Tom Hosker  Shouldn't it be more logical to compare the Chinese dynasties which claimed to be the rightful rulers or overlords of all the world with the European dynasties which claimed to be the rightful rulers or overlords of all the world, and thus with the eastern Roman or "Byzantine" emperors and with the Holy Roman Emperors, than with the monarchs of the little kingdom of England?  Teh Song could be compared to Ottonian, Salian & Hohenstauffen, the Ming to Luxembourg and Habsburg, the Qign to Habsburg and Habsburg-Lorraine..

Comment: Question is rather silly. Except roughly the same time period, nothing substantial connects various European monarchies with Chinese dynasties. Different social systems, different levels of technology, different histories etc ..

Comment: These sorts of comparisons mislead.  It's like the comparisons that equate feudal Japan and feudal Europe.  They are more apt to give wrong impressions to a novice than explain anything.